# Set Filter Values Based on Excel Cells

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, vba

I am trying to set filter values based on values stored in a few cells as opposed to entering it in the dialog box that appears when I select the down arrow under the field I wish to filter.
This is a number filter for the between function (custom auto filter)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can try Advanced Filter under Data > Sort & Filter or can you try vba?

Comment: @ZAT, I do not see a sort and filter option under Advanced Filter..Excel 2013. I only see 'Action..list criteria and criteria range'

Comment: DATA means tab named `DATA`. Whatever, `list criteria=list to be filtered` and `criteria range=list of numbers as criteria for filter`.

Comment: Yea, I realize, however that does not give me the result I am looking for. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (dummy cells used because you did not post any specifics):

```
Sub CustomNoFilterBetween()
With ActiveSheet
    LowerCrt = .Range("B2").Value
    UpperCrt = .Range("B3").Value

    .Range("$C$6:$C$16").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & LowerCrt, _
    Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & UpperCrt
End With
End Sub
```

[image]